# Compact, at a glance indicator of checklist status

Tags: visual-design

What are some good ways to show, at a glance, the status of items in a checklist?

I have some checklists for various people in an organization. I need to show the various states of each person's checklist at a glance. Here's what I have so far:

[image: Example checklist]

The first person has all items in the checklist completed, and the second one has all not completed. Any item not complete has a "ban" sign over it, and any complete don't.

The goal is to show a quick summary of the checklist in a visual, eye-scannable way so it's easy to spot what the user is looking for in large lists of people.

How else could I show this checklist's status in a similarly compact way?

Comment: What is the goal here? Is the goal to find and then encourage those who didn't complete the checklist to do so?

Comment: Rather than repeating the symbols, wouldn't it be easier to show this as a table with ticks in the correct columns for those items completed?

Comment: What is the problem with the current design? Just asking for more ideas doesn't suit this site.

Comment: The goal is for an administrator to oversee who has completed their checklist and who hasn't. So at a glance the admin should be able to see where work is needed.

Comment: @AndrewMartin It would, ut the idea is to show it in a compact space, which is what I attempted here. That's why I'm asking, "is there a better way to show this information in a compact space, that's still eye-scannable"

Comment: The current design is ok except with a long list, it becomes a bit tedious on the eye to scan.

Comment: @RichardDesLonde The compact style that you are using is likely to make it very difficult to read when there are one or two things incomplete for a large number of people. You have a lot of space there so I'm curious about why you think you need a compact display?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using icons, use words that describe what they have to do. Color code them (green for done, orange for in-progress, grey for not-yet-started and red for cancelled) and also add appropriate icons next to them for accessibility purposes (check for done, an X for cancelled etc.)

And of course, test the solution with your users!

Answer (score 1):

First, the "ban" sign ⊘ means just that, ban, block, no access—but not "not started". Second, it obscures the symbol.

Just use color:

[image: task completion]

If you have the information available, you can also color code "started, (not finished)" status:

[image: task completion "started"]

...and add a color legend.

OR, "disappear" the completed tasks:

[image: task completion "hide"]

Add a flyover for more information, such as Start Date and % Completed:

[image: task completion "flyover"]